# RequiredFieldValidation fire But Cancel button of the grid view is not working asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, requiredfieldvalidator

Hi i am using grid view with edit, Delete,Update, Cancel link buttons. It has required field validatore and it fire when i try to update the row without any Values in it and showing error messages in validation summary. **Here i want To Cancel update. But its not working. please help thanks in advance**
i have ADD HTML CODE AND IMAGE

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" DataKeyNames="empid" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
         OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
         EmptyDataText="NO RECORD FOUND">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtempid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("empid") %>' ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblempid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("empid") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtname" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name is required" ControlToValidate="txtname" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"
                        ValidationGroup="Etemplate"  >

                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfname" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ft" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtinsertname" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name is required for insert" ControlToValidate="txtfname" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"
                         ValidationGroup="ft" >

                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Job">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtjob" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("job") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvjob" runat="server" ErrorMessage="job required" ControlToValidate="txtjob" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"
                        ValidationGroup="Etemplate">

                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="txtjob" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("job") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfjob" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtinsertjob" runat="server" ErrorMessage="job is required for insert" ControlToValidate="txtfjob" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"
                         ValidationGroup="ft" > </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdeptname" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("deptname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvdeptname" runat="server" ErrorMessage="dept name required" ControlToValidate="txtdeptname" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"
                         ValidationGroup="Etemplate">

                     </asp:RequiredFieldValidator >
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbldept" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("deptname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfdeptname" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtinsertdeptname" runat="server" ErrorMessage="deptname is required for insert" ControlToValidate="txtfdeptname" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"
                         ValidationGroup="ft">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="operations ">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnupdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btninsert" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ValidationGroup="ft" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server"  ForeColor="Red" />
```

[Grid view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLqn5.png)

Comment: Can you add your relevant code in your question?

Comment: Make sure your `ValidationGroup` names are different in the edit row.

Comment: Validationgroup names are different my main problem is that whenever i want to cancel the update with the blank values the cancel button in the grid view  is not working

Answer (score 1):

I got the Answer Causes Validation false

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"   CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
```